# org.apache.lucene.search.Query vs org.infinispan.query.dsl.Query

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, infinispan

I was using Infinispan 6.0.2 libraries in my application and downgraded the version to 5.3. With Infinispan5.3 the infinispan dsl querires are not supported. Can someone explain what is the difference between org.apache.lucene.search.Query and org.infinispan.query.dsl.Query ? Is there a workaround to run the Infinispan6.0.2. libraries on IBM Websphere servers running on JDK1.6?

Answer (score 0):

You ask two questions: difference between Lucene and DSL Query and compatibility issues of different Infinispan versions with IBM Websphere. For the latter, please start another question describing your problems.

As for the first part: Infinispan uses Lucene to index the data. Lucene Query API is tied to this underlying index, and is limited to Java (and therefore, library=embedded mode).
DSL API was designed to allow

- independence on the underlying index
- independence on the language/runtime.

DSL API can be used both in embedded mode and from HotRod clients in Java and another languages (C++, .NET - though currently it is not implemented).
With independence on the underlying index, index-less queries are supported in addition to Lucene (the data don't need to be indexed before querying them).